# Generate C# project using CMake

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, build-automation, cmake

I'm trying to generate a C# project within an existing C++ CMake code base on Windows. After some research, I could find only two projects that built their own CSharp compilers for CMake:
[gdcm](http://gdcm.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gdcm/Sandbox/CMakeCSharp/) and [kde](http://websvn.kde.org/?revision=1061491&view=revision).

I tried both of them. Unfortunately, the first one failed to generate a C# project. Instead it created a VS C++ project with cs files in it, and because of C++ flags set for linker, the build always failed with errors. After experimenting with the sample project they provided, I wonder whether this could be due to a limitation of the "Visual Studio 8 2005" code generator?

The second project was primarily aimed at Mono, so I wasn't successful with it either.

Has anyone had a positive experience with building C# projects using one of those CMake modules or something else?

Answer (score 57):

As of [CMake 3.8.2](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/release/3.8.html), CSharp project generation is officially supported by CMake.

To build the default Visual Studio 2017 generated C#/WPF project using CMake, create a CMakeList.txt file as follows.

- Project Declaration

  ```
    project(Example VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CSharp)
  ```
- Include CMake [`CSharpUtilities`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/CSharpUtilities.html) if you are planning on using WPF or other designer properties.

  ```
    include(CSharpUtilities)
  ```
- Add all `cs`, `xaml`, `settings`, `properties`

  ```
    add_executable(Example
        App.config
        App.xaml
        App.xaml.cs
        MainWindow.xaml
        MainWindow.xaml.cs

        Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
        Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
        Properties/Resources.resx
        Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
        Properties/Settings.settings)
  ```
- Link designer files, `xaml` files, and other properties files with their corresponding `cs` files

  ```
    csharp_set_designer_cs_properties(
        Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
        Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
        Properties/Resources.resx
        Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
        Properties/Settings.settings)

    csharp_set_xaml_cs_properties(
        App.xaml
        App.xaml.cs
        MainWindow.xaml
        MainWindow.xaml.cs)
  ```
- Set app `App.xaml` properties file as program entry point (if project is a WPF project)

  ```
    set_property(SOURCE App.xaml PROPERTY VS_XAML_TYPE "ApplicationDefinition")
  ```
- Set other `csproj` file flags

  ```
    set_property(TARGET Example PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.6.1")
    set_property(TARGET Example PROPERTY WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)
    // ...
  ```
- Add libraries

  ```
    set_property(TARGET Example PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
        "Microsoft.CSharp"
        "PresentationCore"
        "PresentationFramework"
        "System"
        "System.Core"
        "System.Data"
        "System.Data.DataSetExtensions"
        "System.Net.Http"
        "System.Xaml"
        "System.Xml"
        "System.Xml.Linq"
        "WindowsBase")
  ```

For a working WPF example, see https://github.com/bemehiser/cmake_csharp_example

For a [WinForms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55602125/1787434).

Comment: Sadly this is only supported on Windows

Comment: Generation of Visual Studio projects by CMake is only supported on Windows, probably because Visual Studio itself only has decent support for Windows. (Yes, there is partial support on Mac as well, but not in CMake.)

Comment: Right, but Visual Studio *projects* have been supported by Mono on Linux and Mac for over a decade.

Comment: Does this support mixed projects? I need a Visual Studio solution with c++ libraries and c# projects

Comment: Depending on how you set up your directory structure, yes. For instance, if you have a directory with C++ files which compile into a library, and another directory with C# files, you would use `project(CPPExample VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CPP)` in the C++ folder, build your library target, then utilize that target in the C# project. There may be other more elegant ways to do this as well, but that's how I've done it.

Comment: In addition, you can set the C# language version (which defaults to version 3.0) with the command: `set(CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "/langversion:6")`

Comment: I provided a full CMake example for a Windows Forms application [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55602125/3987854).

Comment: What do three dots `...` mean under the phrase `Set other csproj file flags`? Is it going to work out of the box or do I have to set more flags?

Comment: @KulaGGin It just means "additional code has been omitted for brevity". The dots should not appear in your code. In this case, it represents setting other flags with `set_property` which you deem necessary. The example on Github doesn't contain the dots or additional flags.

Comment: @the_storyteller thanks, I read your answer till the end, checked out the github project and managed to create the WPF project for myself.

Comment: @the_storyteller any way to set the default namespace? I created a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70541921/how-to-set-default-namespace-for-a-c-sharp-project . I checked out the documentation and couldn't find it: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/CSharpUtilities.html

Answer (score 30):

CMake 2.8.9 and up add a `TYPE` parameter to `include_external_msproject` like so:

```
include_external_msproject(
    MyProject MyProject.csproj
    TYPE FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC)
```

This lets you specify that the project is C# (the magic GUID above), otherwise things struggle ([see docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3ainclude_external_msproject)).

You will probably still want to use the `configure_file` template approach mentioned elsewhere with your `.csproj` file to get the right paths into it, unless you're building straight into your source tree.

The good news is that you can wildcard your C# files in the `.csproj.template` file like so:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="${DOS_STYLE_SOURCE_DIR}\**\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And you'll need something like this in your `CMakeLists.txt` to convert CMake's unix-style forwardslash path separators into Windows-style backslashes, otherwise it will compile the files but they won't show up as links in the project in Visual Studio:

```
FILE(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" DOS_STYLE_SOURCE_DIR)
```

Then it's just:

```
CONFIGURE_FILE(MyProject.csproj.template MyProject.csproj)
```

In your `CMakeLists.txt` to configure the template file into a real project file with the right wildcard path.

HTH.

Comment: Could you give a complete example (or link to one) of how to: (1) Copy the source C# folder and files; (2) the .csproj.template and how to use it; and (3) how to update CMakeLists.txt to do all this?

Comment: You don't need to copy the C# source folder/files - they are referenced in-place. The csproj.template file is the same as any other csproj file, except for the wildcard noted above. Just copy one. I've added the actual CONFIGURE_FILE command to my answer, which was the only thing missing.

Comment: Do I need a extra CMakeLists.txt in my C# folder or do all these changes happen in the root CMakeLists.txt?  
If they happen in the root CMakeLists.txt, do I put them before or after the call to include_external_msproject()?

Comment: Got it to work with all the changes in the root CMakeLists.txt.  However, in order to [re-]build my C# projects, I have to unload and reload them every time the `.sln` is [re-]generated otherwise they are "Skipped". Any ideas? I asked about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15859576/135862

Comment: FYI, here's a list of the magic GUIDs for different Visual Studio projects: https://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs

Answer (score 22):

Just in case anyone is still looking for information about this, there is really no reason to generate C# projects with CMake, they are cross platform by design. On Linux, C# projects are generally managed with MonoDevelop which can read .csproj files from visual studio just fine. This should enable cross-platform development of C# projects.
The only potential issue would be if you had native c++ projects mixed with c# projects (like a backend written in c++ with a GUI in c#), in this case just have cmake copy over your .csproj files as though they were data and you should be good to go.
CMake is intended to set up your build environment to be cross platform. This comes in really handy with c++ where code is built in a very different way on linux than on windows (or other OSs if youre into that), but is kind of unnecessary for c# which can execute cross-platform, and, thanks to design decisions by the mono team, can build cross platform. CMake does provide some great tools to automate things, but much of this functionality can be recovered with a properly configured .csproj file. 
Anyway I know this question is over a year old but it's one of the top search results I stumbled on when I was looking up how to do this. I've since made this realization.

Comment: Yes, but while cmake also provides install functionality plain C# projects (csproj) don't. I'd be interested in "make && make install" functionality for C# projects if cmake could provide it.

Comment: It's not hard to set up a post build event for this. Assuming you need to integrate into an existing cmake build system, you can even use the cmake configure_file command to fill in the correct install location.

Comment: There is a good reason to generate C# projects by CMake. If you have mixed native + C++/CLI + C# project with lot of configuration done by CMake, you need the C# project to take the configuration done in CMake into account and refer to the projects generated for C++ and be included in the right solution.

Comment: @Jan again use configure_file (http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:configure_file) for this. Most projects I work on are C++, C++/CLI, and C#, and this works great in lieu of actual cmake support for C#.

Comment: I would say the best reason for generating C# projects using CMake is to get away from .csproj files.  The biggest issue I have with .csproj files is that they are only editable through a queer set of dialogues and the result is an impenetrable XML file.  CMake suffers from neither of these problems.

Comment: @Magnus I would write the msbuild xml by hand when I had to do these

Comment: @Max I'm not surprised, sometimes that's the sort of thing one has to resort to due to lack of good tooling.

Comment: @Magnus with new .csproj format - not anymore. https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/

Comment: C++/CLI is pretty much useless IMO :). I prefer to just use C library and `[DllImport]`

Comment: CMake is just a C/C++ monster with a shitty DSL trying to fix inventors mistakes. No need for that in dotnet world. Even Rust doesn't need such things. Max's answer should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

To piggy-back on the answer provided by @the_storyteller, [CMake v3.8](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/release/3.8.html#c) and greater indeed supports C# as a first-class language. Because a WPF example was already provided, here is a complete CMake example for a simple Windows Forms application. I've provided the optional commands for linking in other libraries built locally in the source tree, and linking 3rd party library dependencies.

Note that Windows Forms applications require the use of the `csharp_set_windows_forms_properties` CMake command, whereas WPF projects use `csharp_set_designer_cs_properties` and `csharp_set_xaml_cs_properties`.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(MyWinFormApp LANGUAGES CSharp)

# Include CMake utilities for CSharp, for WinForm and WPF application support.
include(CSharpUtilities)

# Define the executable, including any .cs files. 
# The .resx and other Properties files are optional here, but including them makes them visible in the VS solution for easy editing. 
add_executable(MyWinFormApp
    App.config
    Form1.cs
    Form1.Designer.cs
    Form1.resx
    Program.cs
    Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
    Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
    Properties/Resources.resx
    Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
    Properties/Settings.settings
)

# Set the .NET Framework version for the executable.
set_property(TARGET MyWinFormApp PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_TARGET_FRAMEWORK_VERSION "v4.6.1")
# Set the executable to be 32-bit.
set_property(TARGET MyWinFormApp PROPERTY WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE)
# Set the C# language version (defaults to 3.0).
set(CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "/langversion:latest")

# Set the source file properties for Windows Forms use.
csharp_set_windows_forms_properties(
    Form1.cs
    Form1.Designer.cs
    Form1.resx
    Program.cs
    Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
    Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
    Properties/Resources.resx
    Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
    Properties/Settings.settings
)

# If necessary, link in other library dependencies that were built locally in this source tree.
target_link_libraries(MyWinFormApp MyLocalLib)

# If necessary, link in other library/DLL references, such as 3rd party libraries.
set_property(TARGET MyWinFormApp PROPERTY 
    VS_DOTNET_REFERENCE_MyThirdPartyLib /path/to/libs/MyThirdPartyLib.dll)

# Add in the .NET reference libraries.
set_property(TARGET MyWinFormApp PROPERTY VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES
    "Microsoft.CSharp"
    "System"
    "System.Core"
    "System.Data"
    "System.Drawing"
    "System.Windows.Forms"
)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Would you consider adding that as a second example (the first will have to be renamed) to my [CMake C# example project on GitHub](https://github.com/bemehiser/cmake_csharp_wpf_example)? If you do add the WinForms example and submit a pull request, I'll rename it to be more generic, and we can link it here as well.

Comment: Just created the pull request. Both WinForm and WPF examples work on VS 2017 and VS 2019.

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to generate a valid solution using the second c# module - kde. 
Although, cmake created a number of .vcproj files while I expected to get .csproj, but I guess that is the only form "Visual Studio 8 2005" generator can offer.

Nevertheless I was able to successfully build this solution and produce executables and dll libraries.

Comment: Update: the fact that cmake created c++ projects with c# source files in them makes the project almost unusable - Intellisense doesn't work, app.config cannot be accessed through the regular means, etc. 
I'm discontinuing further investigation in this direction and switching to MsBuild -based project configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a project with Visual Studio, than take it apart and make CMake write it using `configure_file` command (you'll have to generate a bit of XML with the list of sources) and add it to the solution with `include_external_msproject` (for other generators you'll need to create the custom target to run msbuild on it manually; cmake does not seem to support doing that yet). The project is rather simple, so it should be possible to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to point out that it is now possible to generate C# Projects using the SDK-Style project XML format using CMake 3.23.

Although it is still a release candidate version, it works pretty well with CMake 3.23 rc2. To create C# SDK-style projects use [DOTNET_SDK](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/DOTNET_SDK.html#prop_tgt:DOTNET_SDK) target property.

For example one could use C# SDK-style project with this line

```
set_target_properties(myTarget PROPERTIES DOTNET_SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk")
```

Also remember that you don't need a `project()` command when creating C# Projects with CMake. The `project()` command always creates a new solution which could be useful but not necessary. One can use `enable_language(CSharp)` to declare a Target being a C# Project.

To test C# SDK-style projects I used Visual Studio 2019 with Visual Studio 16 Generator on Windows.