# Form designer view is not available in visual studio 2019 C# CMake project

Tags: c#, winforms, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to port my C# Windows Form project from .csproj to CSharp CMake CMakeLists.txt. I successfully made CMakeLists.txt similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55602125/4003077). The only problem is when the project opened with CMakeLists.txt, the Form Designer is not available (as shown below). Is it any way to fix the problem?

csproj:

[image]

CMakeLists.txt:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second image (from your CMake-generated project) is in a different **View** than the first image. The first image is the **Solution View**, in which the `Form1.cs` and `Form1.Designer.cs` files are *grouped* to show that the Form Designer is available. The CMake (second) image is showing the **Folder View**, which does **not** group the two files together.

CMake does not control what view you see in Visual Studio, your Visual Studio IDE controls this. The toolbar across the top of **Solution Explorer** has a button (called "Switch Views") to switch from a solution view to a folder view (and vice versa). You can use this to switch your perspective back to Solution View so the Form Designer is shown.

---

Note: This button has a bug in Visual Studio 2019 (see [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/596565/cannot-switch-back-to-solution-view-from-folder-vi.html)), so switching back to Solution View may not work as expected. I've worked around this issue by simply closing and re-opening the Solution.

When you open the solution file (via **File > Open > Project/Solution...**), your *default* View should be the **Solution View**, and the Form Designers for your forms sources should be accessible. If you open the solution by doing **File > Open > CMake...**, your default View will be **Folder View**, which is not what you want.

Comment: The **Switch Views** button has 2 options 1- **WindowsFormsApp** (seems folder view) similar to the image I posted 2- **CMake Targets View**. But non of them show Form Designer. (ps:  here is a disabled option which shows **No Solutions Found** !? since the CMake generation finished successfully)

Comment: There will be no **Form Designer** view, only the **Folder View** and **Solution View**. The Form Designer for each source file is only accessible from the **Solution View**. It sounds like your VS2019 version is having the same bug I was experiencing. Try closing then re-opening the solution, the default view upon re-opening should be the **Solution View**. I expanded my answer to include this.

Comment: Nothing happen! This is what I do: 1-File > Close Folder. 2- File > Open > CMake. Even I restart VS! [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc813.png) is my **Switch Views**

Comment: When you do **Open > CMake**, VS2019 will default to **Folder View**. You should open the native Visual Studio project or solution files though (`.sln`). Do **Open > Project/Solution...** and choose your *solution* file (`.sln`) to open in **Solution View**. I expanded my answer again to explain this.

Comment: So after each time CMakeLists.txt changed, I should generate `.sln` again and then open in VS!?

Comment: You can modify your CMake files *within* VS2019. When building your project in VS2019 (**Build > Build Solution**), it will first check if your CMake files were changed. If so, it will re-run CMake for you, you don't have to do this manually. It will then prompt you to *reload* your solution, if the solution has changed; there is no need to close/re-open it manually either. After the solution reloads, your View should be *preserved* so it will still be in **Solution View**.