# CMake how to set default namespace for a C# project?

Tags: cmake

I've managed to generate solution files for a C# WPF solution using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46247927/6693304) to the [Generate C# project using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074144/generate-c-sharp-project-using-cmake/46247927) question.

But as soon as I created my own file, I noticed that the generated namespace was blank, so I went to properties of the project and confirmed that the default namespace is blank:
[image]

I'd like to set default namespace to the name of the project, how do I do it?

I checked out the documentation for [CSharpUtilities](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/CSharpUtilities.html), and googled it, and the only thing that I found related to the problem is this: [VS_GLOBAL_ROOTNAMESPACE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_GLOBAL_ROOTNAMESPACE.html). But I don't know what to do with it. Is it a function? Is it a variable? Where do I put it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to do is to set a property for my target project:

```
set_target_properties(Example
    PROPERTIES
    VS_GLOBAL_ROOTNAMESPACE Example
)
```