# Creating C# and C++/CLR projects in the same solution using CMake (CMake targeting visual studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmake, c++-cli

I want to create a solution in MSVC using CMake that has two projects (in CMake vocabulary one C# executive and one C++/CLR library).

How can I do this? All examples that I found are about one type of project in a CMake (all C++ or C#).

To clarify:

If I want to create a C++/CLR project using CMake, I can write code like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project (TestCppClr)

if (NOT MSVC)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "This CMake files only wirks with MSVC.")
endif(NOT MSVC)


ADD_EXECUTABLE(testCppClr "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp")
set_target_properties(testCppClr PROPERTIES COMMON_LANGUAGE_RUNTIME "")
```

and if I want to create a project targeting C#, I can write something such as this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

project(Example VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CSharp)

if (NOT MSVC)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "This CMake files only wirks with MSVC.")
endif(NOT MSVC)


add_executable(Example
App.config
App.xaml
App.xaml.cs
MainWindow.xaml
MainWindow.xaml.cs

Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
Properties/Resources.resx
Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
Properties/Settings.settings)
```

I cannot find any way to combine these two CMake files, so I can create an executable in C++/CLR and another project in C#.

Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly have both [C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019) and C# in the same CMake project - just enable both languages (C++ and C#) when you call `project()`.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

# Enable both C++ and C# languages.
project (TestCSharpAndCppClr VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX CSharp)

if(NOT MSVC)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "This CMake files only works with MSVC.")
endif(NOT MSVC)

# Create your C++/CLI executable, and modify its properties.
add_executable(testCppClr "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp")
set_target_properties(testCppClr PROPERTIES COMMON_LANGUAGE_RUNTIME "")

# Create your C# executable.
add_executable(Example
App.config
App.xaml
App.xaml.cs
MainWindow.xaml
MainWindow.xaml.cs

Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
Properties/Resources.Designer.cs
Properties/Resources.resx
Properties/Settings.Designer.cs
Properties/Settings.settings)
```

Please note, you should be using CMake 3.8 or greater to get *full* CMake support for C#. Also, your C# example appears to be missing some of the essential CMake commands for CSharp targets, as seen in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46247927/3987854). You should be able to add these commands as necessary to the same `CMakeLists.txt` file to modify the properties of the C# source files and C# target.

Comment: How to define that "testCppClr" is a C++/clr and "Example" is a c# application? in this code, both of them seems similar to each other.

Comment: @mans Well, you can name them something more verbose to tell you and other developers what they are. The C# target name `Example` is pretty vague, so you could change it to `MyCSharpExecutable` or something similar to make it more clear. This would only be for your own sanity; CMake is smart and will *infer* what to build based on the **file extensions** of the source files you provide to the `add_executable` command. So, source files with `.cpp` file extensions will be built into C++ libraries/executables, and `.cs` files will be built into C# libraries/executables.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. Cmalke understands the file extension and uses the appropriate project type for them.