# How do I call windows form c# functions from c++ project?

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, clr

I was working on a windows form project lately and I made some functions in that project that I want to use from another c++ project of mine. My windows form project is creating a .dll already, so I was wondering if I could call my functions thanks to it somehow.

I tried creating a CLR empty project as I know those are supposed to link C++ and C# possible but when I try to use the namespace of my C# classes in the CLR project, visual doesn't find it and tells me the name I'm trying to use must be a namespace, am I missing something?

Here are some images of what I've done:

[Encrypter.cs (the C# class I'm trying to use)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjzOp.png)

[The C++ file in the CLR project trying to use it (I tried several ways of getting my class, I left them all, none worked)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzmf6.png)

[Both projects are next to each other in the same solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSuFH.png)

To sum up my questions:

1. Do CLR projects work both ways with C++ and C#? I find very few mentions of C++ projects using C# functions, but much more of the other way around.
2. Is it possible to call windows from C# functions from a C++ or CLR project, or do I have to make another C# project that creates a .dll ?
3. If I'm going the right way with what I've already done, how do I use my C# class in my CLR project?

EDIT: For anyone maybe coming through here, I found the solution. Turns out I did miss something in my setup, when selecting the CLR project and going in the "Project" menu on top of visual studio, you can then go to "Add Reference" and select your C# dll. Once I did this, the CLR project saw all my C# classes and functions.

Comment: does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4818252/16822867) your question?

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62386383/creating-c-sharp-and-c-clr-projects-in-the-same-solution-using-cmake-cmake-ta) may give you some more clues.

Comment: I finally found the solution, it was in a stack overflow post but I can't find it anymore sadly, I edited the main post. Thank you both for your answers!